# Verify if a file was created shell

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, directory

I have to write a shell script that will monitor some folders given in the command and give a message if a certain file will be created inside them (the name of the file will be read from keyboard).

Can anyone tell me why is this not working?

```
#!/bin/sh
f=`read filename`
isIn=0
for dir in $*
do
    if [ ! -d $dir ]
    then
        echo $dir is not a directory.
    fi
    for i in `find $dir -type f`
    do
        if [ $f=$i ]
        then
            echo The file $f already exists.
            isIn=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $isIn -eq 0 ]
    then
        sleep 20
        isIn=0
        for i in `find $dir -type f`
        do
            if [ $f=$i ]
            then
                echo The file was created\!
                isIn=1
                break
            fi
        done
    fi
    if [ $isIn -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo The file was not created\!
    fi
done
```

The idea i used was that i take all the files from the directory and verify is the file isn't already there. 
If it is - show message and move to the next directory. 
If not then I 'wait'. if in the time i waited that certain file was created, it would have appeared in the list of all files, and i check for it.

My problem is that no matter what file I read from the keyboard, i would get the message "The file already exists." without telling me the name of the file.

Comment: What are you expecting `f='read filename'` to do? (That's not formatted correctly; I replaced the backticks by apostrophes. See the second line of your script.) The `read` function doesn't print anything to stdout; rather it stores the input in `$filename`. `$f` is going to be the empty string.

Comment: it should read from the keyboard. I need to put it in between ` ` to work and I need to give him a parameter

Comment: No, you don't need to use backticks. Just write `read filename`; it will set the variable `$filename` to whatever the user types. The use `$filename` rather than `$f`.

Comment: if you put apostrophes is not correct. but with backticks i used it before and it worked. @KeithThompson

Comment: so i've tried it with `f=read filename`. and i get this in line 2: filename: not found. @KeithThompson

Comment: ok, i just checked. it did not worked before either. so what should i do? @KeithThompson

Comment: You should do `read filename`. *Not* `f=read filename`. And then you should refer to `$filename`, removing all references to `$f`.

Comment: And change `if [ $f=$i ]` into `if [ "$filename" = "$i" ]` (with spaces and quotes). When $filename is empty you will still have a valid equation.

Comment: After testing and writing `echo $dir is not a directory.` you should add a line `continue` : You do not want to process the invalid dir and want to continue the loop with the next param.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `` f=`read filename` `` with the correct usage `read f` or `read -p filename: f`.
2. `find $dir -type f` prints the full file name including the directory path. Since you want just the basename, replace both lines

   ```
       for i in `find $dir -type f`
   ```

   with

   ```
       for i in `find $dir -type f -printf '%f\n'`
   ```
3. Each operator and operand in `[` `]` must be a separate argument. Thus replace both lines

   ```
           if [ $f=$i ]
   ```

   with

   ```
           if [ "$f" = $i ]
   ```